# Is there more efficient way to keep custom object array unique by each pagination data feeds?

Tags: ios, swift, set, nscountedset

In the tableView's willDisplay checks latest cell and then trigger new request for upcoming datas cited as pagination.

I want to keep that custom object array's IDs as unique with upcoming datas too.

I tried below solution to make it, but I wonder that Is there anything to do more efficiently?

```
let idSet = NSCountedSet(array: (newDatas + self.ourDatas).map { $0.id })
let arr = (newDatas + self.ourDatas).filter { idSet.count(for: $0.id) == 1 }
self.ourDatas = arr // ourDatas is dataSource of tableView
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Also above way mixes all datas, how can I continue keeping it as ordered?

Comment: Have you tried group dictionary for ordering

Comment: Can you more clearly explain what you are trying to do? Why do you need a set of identifiers?  Why are you reloading the whole tableview?  You should just insert the additional rows. It will be smoother

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi, for example backend sending objects with same id which I already have in my list. I don't want to insert it. Also checking it with .contains can be bad for keeping efficient I think. That's why I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @Kudos No, I didn't use. I don't know that is it possible to make this case as ordered?

Comment: Ok. Just create a `Set` of the ids you already had, then you can quickly and efficiently check with the set `contains` the id. If it does, then skip the item. If it doesn't then add the item to your array and add the id to the set.  The array keeps the order and it doesn't matter that the set is unordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep two properties; your array of items (`ourDatas`) and a set of ids (`var ourIds = Set<String>()`. I am assuming your  ids are `Strings`

You can do something like this

```
var insertedRows = [IndexPath]()
for newItem in newDatas {
   if !ourIds.contains(newItem.id) {
      insertedRows.append(IndexPath(item:self.ourDatas.count,section:0))
      ourIds.insert(newItem.id)
      ourDatas.append(newItem)
   }
}

if !insertedRows.empty {
   self.tableView.insertRows(at: insertedRows, with:.automatic)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so you mean that `let ourIds = NSCountedSet(array: (self.ourDatas).map { $0.id })`

Comment: No, there is no need to use `NSCountedSet` - you don't care how many times an id appears, only whether it does or not, so a normal Swift set is fine.  You also don't need to use a map, since every time you add an object to your `ourDatas` array you add its id to the set. Over time the set just gets more and more ids (your set should be a property just like `ourDatas`)

Answer (score 0):

I have a helper extension for Array for this. It "reduces" an array having only "distinct" elements:

```
public extension Array where Element: Identifiable {
    var distinct: [Element] {
        var elements = Set<Element.ID>()
        return filter { elements.insert($0.id).inserted }
    }
}
```

based on the element's `id`. That is, you need to have your elements conform to `Identifiable` - which is very useful anyway when showing them in a TableView or List.

So, when you receive a new array of elements, just do this:

```
    self.elements = (self.elements + newElements).distinct
```

A small test for Playgrounds:

```
extension Int: Identifiable {
    public var id: Int { self }
}

var a = [1,2,3,4,5]
var b = [1,2,3,6,7]

print((a + b).distinct)
```

Console:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```